# Python3: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

I'm tryin to add commas to big numbers in my code. When I isolate the code it works:

```
num = str(12354343)
print("{:,}".format(float(num)))
```

But inside my code I receive the error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'.

```
def commafy(x):
    x = "{:,}".format(float(x))
    return x

i=1

d = resp.json()
for result in d['results']:
    #print(result['campaign_name'])
    data[i] = {'Source': 'Taboola', 'Campaign': result['campaign_name'], 'Impr.': commafy(result['impressions']), 'CTR': round(result['ctr'],2) + "%", 'Spent': result['spent']}
    i+=1
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you,

Comment: You are doing a lot in the line `data[i] = ...`. I suggest you break out the smaller pieces and assign them to variables. This will help you narrow down the problem to the code that is actually causing the error. (Hint: The error is **not** caused calling `format()`.

Comment: Also note that the error you put in the title says something about `+` but there is no `+` in your `commafy()` function. This should be a hint that you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice for your explaination. It was helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere:

> ```
> 'CTR': round(result['ctr'],2) + "%",
> ```

The result of [round](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round) is is a `float` and you are trying to concattenate it with `'%'` which is a string.

You are not `commafy`ìng the float result here ...

```
'CTR': f"{round(result['ctr'],2)}%", # should work for 3.6+ (string interpolation syntax)
```

or

```
'CTR': "{}%".format(round(result['ctr'],2)), # should work for below 3.6
```